# How to change a value on a specific hour of the day

Tags: php, mysql, variables, alter-table

I'm starting a project in PHP with MySQL that the idea is to not only to compare but give users (drivers) what the taxi-meter should charge and use those values to make other setting like for example a Fare Calculator (future section) for Taxi Rides.

What I'm looking is to change values from a table every time the clock hits 6:00 am and 11:00 pm, for example:

My variables:

```
$base_price
$price_per_unit_distance
$price_per_unit_time
```

My default values for each variables are:

Base Price: 8.10
Price Per Unit Distance: 2.20
Price Per Unit Time: 2.20

The idea is that since 6:00 am o'clock does values stay and when the clock hits 11:00 pm the values automatically change to:

Base Price: 10.10
Price Per Unit Distance: 3.20
Price Per Unit Time: 3.20

And so On (continue the job)

Table Name is **Settings**, I'm attaching an image of my table:

[image: click to open image]

Any ideas on how can I make this work? I'm thinking on an if and else statement or an alter table, but how can I make it change automatically (by itself) and change on the specific hours working on a **specific time zone**? (This is if the driver is in another country).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: have you considered having prices in a separate table? That way you could query for the price based on the hour the time is currently at.

Comment: hello @KarlViiburg. No, actually I have the Prices on the same table because I alter the values manually with a form (like an admin section(. I´m already using that table on other sections of the page because of the values. Putting the Prices on different tables would be a lot of work :(

Comment: I concur with @KarlViiburg, having a separate price config table with times is your best chance. If you hard code this into php, then you will have to change your code every time these parameters change.

Comment: Thanks for you replay @Shadow. Is there some info of it I can see or any code suggestions for that configuration about the separate price config table with times? appreciated, I guess that´s the best option.

Comment: There is no generic approach, you need to include all the information within your pricing table that is required for your application to select the appropriate price. Time, time zone, and location all seems to play a role in this according to your description, but you must know your requirements better, than I do.

Comment: Use an EVENT...

Comment: @RickJames Hello, sorry didn't got a notification for you answer and until now that I opened the app saw you comment. I tried the events on phpMyAdmin and worked awesome. Thanks, that was what I was looking for. Great!